# Can't apply ".onChanged" method for TapGesture in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

I'm getting the following error if trying to run the code below:

```
// Type 'TapGesture.Value' (aka '()') cannot conform to 'Equatable'
```

Here's a code:

```
struct PressButton: View {
    
    @Binding var pressed: Bool
                
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {            
            Circle()
                .gesture(
                    TapGesture()
                        .onChanged { _ in pressed = true }    // ERROR
                        .onEnded { _ in pressed = false }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

However, `.onEnded { _ in }` method is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gesture/onchanged(_:)) of `onChanged` states, the method is only available on `Gesture` when `Gesture.Value` is `Equatable`. However, `TapGesture.Value` is `Void`, which is not `Equatable`, hence `TapGesture` doesn't have the `onChanged` method.

However, `onEnded` is available on all `Gesture` conformant types.

A `TapGesture` holds no state, it is only called **after** the tap has happened.

What you are looking for is [`LongPressGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/longpressgesture), which does expose state as a `Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no

```
.onChanged { _ in pressed = true }
```

modifier with `TapGesture`  please check other ones which have it

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-use-gestures-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

I've found a working solution with `DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0)`:

```
struct DrawButton: View {
    
    @Binding var pressed: Bool
                
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {              
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(pressed ? .red : .black)

                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0)
                    .onChanged { _ in pressed = true }
                    .onEnded { _ in pressed = false }
                )
        }
    }
}
```